# Is it possible to use as an external monitor 2013 iMac 21.5 late edition from MacBook Pro 2015?

Tags: macbook-pro, display, imac

Is it possible to use as an external monitor 2013 iMac 21.5 late edition from MacBook Pro 2015 Early Edition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You will need a Thunderbolt 2 cable. You will also need a keyboard and/or mouse for the 2013 iMac. This is required so you can enter the Command + F2 key combination to put the iMac is target display mode. Also, you will have to have installed a version for MacOS on the iMac that works with target display mode. Basically, High Sierra or an earlier version of macOS compatible with the the 2013 iMac. The 2015 MacBook Pro can have macOS unto the current version (Cataline) installed.

Note: It is possible to install a AppleScript application on the MacBook Pro, that will eliminate the need for the keyboard and/or mouse to be connected to the iMac. Basically, the AppleScript sends the Command + F2 key combination to the iMac over the Thunderbolt 2 cable.

One possible source for [a Thunderbolt 2 cable is OWC](https://eshop.macsales.com/item/OWC/CBLTB3MWH/).

Comment: Can I just run the most recent macOS? Or it needs to be an older version to work with target display mode?

Comment: @KcFnMi: I have a iMac (21.5-inch, Mid 2011) with High Sierra installed. Also, I have a iMac (21.5-inch, Late 2013) with both High Sierra and Catalina installed. Target display mode works with either Mac regardless of the version of macOS running on the 2013 iMac.

Comment: In other words: 2011 iMac running High Sierra as a second display for the 2013 iMac running High Sierra **works**. 2011 iMac  running High Sierra as a second display for the 2013 iMac running Catalina **works**. 2013 iMac running High Sierra as a second display for the 2011 iMac running High Sierra **works**. 2013 iMac running Catalina as a second display for the 2011 iMac running High Sierra **works**.

Comment: I assume what would not work would be if both machines were running Mojave or Catalina. Unfortunately, I can not test this because the 2011 iMac can not run either of these newer versions of macOS.

Comment: I assume what would not work would be if both machines were running Mojave or Catalina. Unfortunately, I can not test this because the 2011 iMac can not run either of these newer versions of macOS. I assume this is what is meant by the statement: "*Target display mode requires macOS High Sierra or earlier. It does not work with macOS Mojave or later.*" which is found on the Apple website [Use your iMac as a display with target display mode](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204592). **Or, maybe the article is wrong and needs to be updated!**